# Calling a method from the super-class but using a local variable from the sub-class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Say I have a class `alpha` that has a method:

```
public boolean isValid(char character) 
{
    for (char validChar : VALID_CHARACTERS) {
        if (character == validChar) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the array:

```
public static final char[] VALID_CHARACTERS = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'w' };
```

And then I have a subclass `beta` that extends `alpha` and I want to call `alpha`'s `isValid()` method in `beta`, but I want to use a new list of valid characters. How would I go about doing that? If I call the `isValid` method it will default to using the `VALID_CHARACTERS` from `alpha` and not the ones from `beta`.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a method in class `alpha` :

```
public char[] getValidCharacters() 
{
    return VALID_CHARACTERS;
}
```

Then you can override this method in the sub-class `beta`.

And you use that method instead of accessing `VALID_CHARACTERS` directly.

Comment: Actually you can not. There is no such thing as overriding static methods in java.

Comment: @kamil Thanks for your comment. It was a typo. It wasn't supposed to be a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the method to request `VALID_CHARACTERS` as parameter

```
public boolean isValid(char character, char[] valids) {
    for (char validChar : valids) {
        if (character == validChar) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and another method to make `VALID_CHARACTERS` as the default parameter

```
public boolean isValid(char character) {
   return isValid(character,VALID_CHARACTERS);
}
```

Then, in your subclass, you could override the second method and change `VALID_CHARACTERS` for for your new set of valid characters

```
public boolean isValid(char character) {
    return isValid(character,foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a protected method in your alpha class say setValidCharacter(char[]) which takes a character array as input and assigns them to the VALID_CHARACTERS.
You will have to change VALID_CHARACTER to **not be FINAL** else you wont be able to modify them.

Then in your subclass beta you can call the setValidCharacter(char[]) method and pass it the new array before you call the isValid method.